# show radiobutonlist in datalist with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, datalist, radiobuttonlist

I have two dropdownlist and i want when fist and second dropdownlist triger then fill updatepanel_sehiri_izmir_radiolist but i cant create dynamic radiobutonlist.i think use datalist and radiobuton list .but i cant run code

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel_sehiri_izmir_radiolist" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="True"
   UpdateMode="Conditional">
      <ContentTemplate>
      <asp:DataList ID="DataList_sehiri_izmir_yeni" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource_sehir_izmir"
      OnItemCommand="DataList_sehiri_izmir_yeni_ItemCommand">
          <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rb_sehiri_izmir" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
              CommandArgument="gonder" RepeatColumns="1" RepeatLayout="Flow" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rb_sehiri_izmir_SelectedIndexChanged">
              <asp:ListItem id="TestedYes" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("imp_id") %>' Text='<%# Eval("imp_id") %>' />
              <asp:ListItem id="TestedNo" runat="server" Value="False" Text="No" />
              </asp:RadioButtonList>
        </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:DataList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource_sehir_izmir" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Web_KentrehberiConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Important_places]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="drp_sehiri_izmir_ulke_adi" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="drp_sehiri_izmir_sehir_adi" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
        </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```